# Episode 5: Order Up constantly repeats requests for installation, and never lets me play

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-story-mode

So I just downloaded Minecraft Story Mode Episode 5: Order Up, and it told me to install it by going to main menu. I accepted, and it sent me to the main menu. However, the arrow was still on download content.

When I select Episode 5, again, it still tells me to go back to the main menu. The process just repeats itself. I am playing on Xbox 360. How do I fix this?

Comment: What platform? If PC, is this the Steam version?

Comment: It's also worth noting that Telltale are having server issues at the moment due to the high traffic from people downloading the latest episode.

Comment: @Studoku Xbox 360.

Comment: One thing I would recommend is not promoting comment-answers. This sounds like a server related problem, if so many people are having the issues, and the servers are being brought down from high traffic. There seems to be a lot of reports that this series is known for day one game breakers, so waiting it out seems like the best option. At the time when this issue was posted to [TrueAchievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/forum/viewthread.aspx?tid=785852), only one user had actually managed to play the game.

Comment: @Timelord64 who was it?

Comment: @Jim Jones I could not say, it comes from other users reports at the time (TA also logs "playing a game" via unlocking the achievements, so that does not mean to say others had not played a very small amount). Just speculation, but if the servers are being strained from so many users accessing them, it is not unlikely that there would be issues connecting or downloading from them, which is why the first suggestion with issues like this is to 'wait it out'

Comment: @Timelord64 okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug with the Xbox 360 version. Telltale have commented that they are working on a fix, though have not yet mentioned an ETA.

https://twitter.com/telltalegames/status/715053980028678144

Comment: Thanks. It's lucky they are going to fix it. I can't wait to play it today!

Comment: It's fixed now. I played the Episode 5.